# How do I insert outputted data into a column on mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a column with numbers and I need to find the difference of that from 10 and insert all the values in parallel in a different column. Can anyone tell me how to get this data into a new column under the name "10-data" and update the same table?

Comment: Update your table and set the value to 10 - YourColumn?

Comment: Sample syntax please?

Comment: I could provide you the syntax but this is very basics of data manipulation. You need to research how to do an update statement. And you haven't provided much for detail other than some extremely vague description.

Comment: Okay. So, it is this. I have a column called scores. they're all less than 10. I need to make another column that shows differences of each of the score from 10. Like say player1 has score of 5 and I need a new value, 10-5=5 which is 10-score. If it's 6, 10-6=4. Like that. I tried update command but it showed an error

Comment: Perhaps you could share what you tried and the error? Did you add the new column to your table? Have you looked at computed columns?

Comment: I have done update table set diff=10-scores;
And one more column is match_date and I need to find the time passed in months since match date.  Say it happened in march, 2018, it will show curdate()-match_date/30 for getting in months. These both show wrong values as results in the new column.

Comment: The error is that the answers are wrong which I can't understand why.

Comment: I can't see your screen and you haven't shared any real details yet. I am not a mysql person but this is pretty much the same for any database. Simply saying the answer are wrong is NOT helpful. I don't know what you are getting or what you are expecting. You need to provide create table scripts and insert statements so others can help.

Comment: Show us the SQL statement you tried and a few rows of data with the "wrong" result you are getting. You want answers, don't you?

Comment: Hi. It works. It was my mistake in typing the wrong numbers in the basic database.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would check my basic database first before asking questions from now.